# How to convert List<Object[]> into List<List<Object>> for GoogleSheet ValueRange

Tags: java, arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write report from hibernate resultset which returns result as List<Object[]>
In order to send this data to google sheet API I need to convert it into List<List>
I have tried several ways but getting following error

"message" : "Invalid data[1]: Invalid values[1][0]: list_value

following is the code I tried but no luck

It might a very dumb thing to ask here but anyone if possible please help

```
List<Object> allData = new ArrayList<>();
      List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Object[] obj : reportParameters.getDataSource().getResultSet()){
        allData.add(Arrays.asList(obj));
      }
      values.add(allData);
      ValueRange sheetData = new ValueRange()
          .setValues(values)
          .setRange("A2");
      body.add(sheetData);
```

Comment: Could you post more detail such as stack trace.

Comment: try change ``allData.add(Arrays.asList(obj));`` to ``allData.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj));``

Comment: I can't understand why you have the two lists "allData" and "values". As far as I can see only one is required in your impl

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Where's `reportParameters` coming from? And which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<List<Object>> values = reportParameters.getDataSource().getResultSet()
   .stream()
   .map(Arrays::asList)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it worked thanks..!
though I am not facing different issue as it seems like Google sheet API does not accept "\n "
journey continues....

Comment: different issue = progress!